# configure oracle jdbc driver in jboss

Tags: jboss, netbeans6.8, jdbc

i'm new to jboss, i wish to setup a development server on my local machine to be used with netbeans, under windows xp; I need to install the oracle jdbc driver on it. I've searched the web and all the articles i found say to copy the jar in the server default folder. Will it be visible also to all and minimal folder ? there's another way to configure drivers without physically moving the jar to the folder ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JBOSS has to have the Oracle JDBC driver JAR in the CLASSPATH, so it has to be in the server /lib directory.  It's visible to the app server and all deployed apps if the JAR is in that location.

This is necessary but not sufficient for configuration connection pools.  You still have to set them up in JBOSS.